TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1)
I'm getting the following error while trying to test whether addresses.
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

const tokens = (n) => {
    return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), 'ether')
}

describe('Escrow', () => {

    let buyer, seller, inspector, lender;
    let realEstate, escrow;

    beforeEach(async () =>{
        [buyer, seller, inspector, lender] = await ethers.getSigners();

        console.log(buyer.address)
        console.log(seller.address)
        console.log(inspector.address)
        console.log(lender.address)

        // Deploy the RealEstate
        const RealEstate = await ethers.getContractFactory('RealEstate');
        realEstate = await RealEstate.deploy();
        // Mint
       let transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).mintFunc("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTudSYeM7mz3PkYEWXWqPjomRPHogcMFSq7XAvsvsgAPS");
       await transaction.wait();

       // Deploy Escrow
       const Escrow = await ethers.getContractFactory('Escrow')
       escrow = await Escrow.deploy(
            lender.address,
            inspector.address,
            seller.address,
            realEstate.address,
       )
      
    })


    describe('Deployments', () => {
        it('Returns NFT address', async () => {
            const result = await escrow.nftAddress()
            expect(result).to.be.equal(realEstate.address)
        })
    
        it('Returns seller', async () => {
            const result = await escrow.seller()
            expect(result).to.be.equal(seller.address)
        })
    
        it('Returns inspector', async () => {
            const result = await escrow.inspector()
            expect(result).to.be.equal(inspector.address)
        })
    
        it('Returns lender', async () => {
            const result = await escrow.lender()
            expect(result).to.be.equal(lender.address)
        })
    })

})

While executing the tests using npx hardhat test command, I'm getting the following error:
Escrow
    Deployments
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC
0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906
      1) "before each" hook for "Returns seller"


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Escrow
       "before each" hook for "Returns seller":
     TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1)     
      at makeError (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:687:21)
      at assert (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
      at assertArgument (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:727:5)
      at resolveAddress (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\address\checks.ts:122:19)
      at D:\Blockchain Projects\Zillow Clone\millow\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:172:60
      at ParamType.#walkAsync (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments.ts:779:24)
      at ParamType.walkAsync (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments.ts:797:24)
      at D:\Blockchain Projects\Zillow Clone\millow\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:170:22
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at resolveArgs (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:169:37)



As, RealEstate is a contract that you’re deploying, so you should get its address using await realEstate.getAddress() instead of realEstate.address, like:
escrow = await Escrow.deploy(
     lender.address,
     inspector.address,
     seller.address,
     await realEstate.getAddress()
)


It's work. Thank You Very much.

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
